# Ocaml can't find Unix module

Tags: unix, ocaml, opam

I (re-)installed Ocaml on OS X using the following steps:

```
> brew uninstall ocaml
> brew uninstall opam
> brew install ocaml
> brew install opam
> opam init
> eval `opam config env`
> opam switch 4.02.1
> opam install batteries core
```

I then tried to compile this program:

```
open Unix
open Printf

let main () =
    match fork () with
    | 0 -> printf "child\n"
    | pid -> printf "parent\n"

let _ = main ()
```

I compiled using this command:

```
ocamlc -o fork fork.ml
```

But I get an error:

```
File "fork.ml", line 1:
Error: Error while linking fork.cmo:
Reference to undefined global `Unix'
```

In fact, I was getting this error before reinstalling; that is why I reinstalled in the first place. But the problem persists and I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`unix` library is not linked by default, so you need to pass some linking flags, to make it work, e.g.,

```
 ocamlc unix.cma fork.ml -o fork
```

If you don't want to know anything about `cma`, you can use `ocamlbuild`, instead of ocamlc:

```
 ocamlbuild -lib unix fork.native
```

Or even more general

```
 ocamlbuild -pkg unix fork.native
```

The latter (with `pkg` option) would be a preferred way, since it will allow you to specify any package installed with `opam`. E.g., if you would ever try to use `lwt`, the you can just link with it with

```
 ocamlbuild -pkg lwt fork.native
```

Answer (score 6):

For those getting this error while using the OCaml interactive toplevel, the command line syntax is similar to that required by `ocamlc`:

```
ocaml unix.cma
```

Comment: You can also load modules after starting up the toplevel using the `#load` command.